# Declare a function that takes a string (as an argument) and returns False if the string is less than 6 characters long. Otherwise, True is returned

Tags: python, list, function, return, generator

After the function declaration, read (using the input function) a list of city names written on a single line separated by a space. Then, using the list generator and the generated function, generate a list of city names at least six characters long from the input list.

This is my code:

```py
def is_large(lst):
    for i in lst:
        if len(i) < 6:
            print(lst)
            return False
        else:
            return True

print(is_large(str(input())))
```

`input: London Paris Nant Munich Krakow`

`Output: London Munich Krakow`

Comment: I see you have written some code in python. Is there a question here? Have you tried your code?

Comment: What is your question? BTW: You need to split the input into words, and you need to print the words that are **at least** 6 characters long, not the whole list. Since in the first iteration you `return` from the function, there will not be a second iteration ... ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So according to your post title, I believe this is what you're asking for:

```
def isWordAllowed(word, allowedLength):
    if (len(word) >= allowedLength):
        return True
    return False
```

Then call the function on your list of words:

```
list = input().split()
for word in list:
    if (isWordAllowed(word, 6)):
        print(word)
```